# Comparing two columns in a data frame for matches and from this creating a new data frame that contains the matches

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, match, columnsorting

please can you help me again?

I have a data frame that contains 4 columns, which are either a gene symbol or a rank that I have assigned the gene symbol like this:

```
     mb_rank  mb_gene  ts_rank  ts_gene
[1]  1        BIRCA    1        MYCN
[2]  2        MYCN     2        MOB4
[3]  3        ATXN1    3        ABHD17C
[4]  4        ABHD17C  4        AEBP2
5 etc... for up to 6000 rows in some data sets. 
the ts columns are usually a lot longer than the mb columns.
```

I want to arrange the data so that non-duplicates are removed thereby leaving only genes that appear in both columns of the data frame e.g.

```
     mb_rank  mb_gene  ts_rank  ts_gene
[1]  2        MYCN     1        MYCN
[2]  4        ABHD17C  3        ABHD17C
```

In this example of the desired outcome, the non-duplicated genes have been removed leaving only genes that appeared in both lists to begin with.

I have tried many things like:

```
`df[df$mb_gene %in% df$ts_gene,]`
```

but it doesn't work and seems to hit and miss some gene 
2) I attempted to write an `IF` function but my skills are to limited.

I hope I have described this well enough but if I can clarify anything please ask, I'm really stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add sample data with `dput(head(df,n))` for better reproducibility.

Comment: Im sorry, Im not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: does this work: `df[df$mb_gene == df$ts_gene,]`?

Comment: This is a longer [version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of my comment. Essentially, it's currently not straightforward to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `data.frame`, typically a row is a complete observation, meaning that all data in it correlates (somehow) with the rest. In a survey, one row is either one person (all questions) or one question for one person. In your data here, though, your first row `BIRCA` and `MYCN` are completely separate, meaning you want to remove one without removing the other. In a "data-science-y" view, this to me suggests your data is improperly shaped.

In order to do what you want, we need to split them into separate frames.

```r
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
mb_rank  mb_gene  ts_rank  ts_gene
1        BIRCA    1        MYCN
2        MYCN     2        MOB4
3        ATXN1    3        ABHD17C
4        ABHD17C  4        AEBP2")

df1 <- df[,1:2]
df2 <- df[,3:4]
df1
#   mb_rank mb_gene
# 1       1   BIRCA
# 2       2    MYCN
# 3       3   ATXN1
# 4       4 ABHD17C
df2
#   ts_rank ts_gene
# 1       1    MYCN
# 2       2    MOB4
# 3       3 ABHD17C
# 4       4   AEBP2
```

From here, we can use `intersect` to find genes in common:

```r
incommon <- intersect(df1$mb_gene, df2$ts_gene)
df1[df1$mb_gene %in% incommon,]
#   mb_rank mb_gene
# 2       2    MYCN
# 4       4 ABHD17C
df2[df2$ts_gene %in% incommon,]
#   ts_rank ts_gene
# 1       1    MYCN
# 3       3 ABHD17C
```

If you are 100% certain that you will always have the same number of rows in each, then you can merely `cbind` these together:

```r
cbind(
  df1[df1$mb_gene %in% incommon,],
  df2[df2$ts_gene %in% incommon,]
)
#   mb_rank mb_gene ts_rank ts_gene
# 2       2    MYCN       1    MYCN
# 4       4 ABHD17C       3 ABHD17C
```

However, if there is a chance that there will be different numbers in each, then you will run into problems. If the number of one is a multiple of the other, you will get "recycling" of data and a warning, but you will still get data (which I think is a mistake):

```r
cbind(
  df1[df1$mb_gene %in% incommon,],
  df2
)
# Warning in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
#   row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
#   mb_rank mb_gene ts_rank ts_gene
# 1       2    MYCN       1    MYCN
# 2       4 ABHD17C       2    MOB4
# 3       2    MYCN       3 ABHD17C
# 4       4 ABHD17C       4   AEBP2
```

If not a multiple, though, you'll just get an error:

```r
cbind(
  df1[df1$mb_gene %in% incommon,],
  df2[1:3,]
)
# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3
```

I suggest that you think about this storage structure, as I believe it defeats assumptions that some tools make about rows of a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
df_new is your new dataframe.

`df_new = df[df['mb_gene'] == df['ts_gene']]`

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it's hard to know about edge cases. In any case, it sounds like a relational table join. Have you tried:

```
d1 = select(df, c(mb_rank, mb_gene))
d2 = select(df, c(ts_rank, ts_gene))
merge(d1, d2, by.x="mb_gene", by.y="ts_gene")
```